# Notification on Unity after i3 desktop removal

Tags: notification, notify-osd, i3-wm

I installed i3 desktop environment and then removed it via software manager since I didn't like it very much.

Now I started to use unity (default) back again. However, now I have a white over blue notifications on the upper left of my screen. I usually see them when wifi is connected or I received an email.

This notification also appears on the login screen and does not let me to write my password during the check of preferred wirelesses.

I need to remove this notification thing.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove dunst i3 i3-wm i3lock i3status suckless-tools
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
```

That will hopefully clear this up.

Comment: log out/in for changes to take effect